# Text from SQL Server to a label

Tags: c#, sql-server, label

How do I select one column from my SQL Server and put it into a label, and then the label always shows the newest (I have `Datetime`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good article for you to read through and follow. There's 4 parts to it. You'll find your answers in there plus learn the basics.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you should go learn the basics on everything first, but I'll give you a pointer here..

Let's say your table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    DateSaved datetime,
    MyLabel varchar(25)
)
```

So you have one datetime field and one field for your label.  You now need a stored procedure to get this data out of your sql server so.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMyLabel
AS

/* Order it so that your dates are descending, meaning newest rows are first. */
select top 1 MyLabel from MyTable
order by DateSaved desc
GO

/* Grant rights to a user for your SqlConnection later.  I'll just call it WebUser. */
GRANT EXECUTE TO WebUser ON GetMyLabel
GO
```

Now your SQL is done.  So now time for your coding.  I'll assume you are using c# (.NET).

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

....

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string myLabelText = Get_MyLabel;

   if (myLabelText != null)
      MyLabel.Text = myLabelText;
}

private void Get_MyLabel(string connStr)
{
    string myLabelText;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        // Returns a single column from the first row of the query
        string myLabelText = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();                
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null && conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            conn.Close()
    }

    return myLabelText;
}
```

and that should do it.  Good luck!